# Why doesn't exception work?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

I have a python code, which i want to raise exception:

```
def main():
    try:
        if testfile == 'testfile':
            write_file(create_output())
            print_file()
            return 0
    except:
        return 1
```

Even if testfile != 'testfile' function doesn't return 1. Why ?

Comment: Perhaps no exception is being raised. If you want to raise an exception, use the ... `raise` keyword :) Your last comment suggests that you want rather and `if`...`else` construct not `try`...`except`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this code in the first place? (i.e., why is this question tagged [tag:unit-testing]?)

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your last sentence, I think you actually want to use [`if/else`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) here:

```
def main():
    if testfile == 'testfile':
        write_file(create_output())
        print_file()
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

[`try/except`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) is for catching/handling errors, not doing one thing or another based on a condition.  That is what `if/else` is for.

Answer (score 2):

You're not raising any kind of exception. You're simply handling any exception that might be raised. Try using `assert` if you're determined to handle this via exceptions. This will raise an `AssertionError` if `testfile` does not equal `'testfile'`:

```
def main():
    try:
        assert testfile == 'testfile'
        write_file(create_output())
        print_file()
        return 0
    except:
        return 1
```

Otherwise as iCodez points out, it is more appropriate in this circumstance to use `if/else`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't understand what an exception is and when it is raised.
A comparison between two strings will return a boolean, it will not raise an exception.
Exceptions are for errors. If testfile != 'testfile' you don't get an error in your code, but simply a conditional statement that is False.
I suggest you to read some [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to raise an exception, it must be thrown first. In the code block above that won't happen unless write_file or print_file raises the exception. You'll want to do an if/else to return 1. If this is the testfile == 'testfile, do something, else return 1.